# FFMPEG Interframe to intraframe without 'converting' or losing data

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, file-conversion

I'm new to this so I apologise I couldn't find the answer after searching.

I am just ripping some video content for my film show-reel (specifically the Lego movie bluray) and came across some issues. When using 'makeMKV' and 'xMedia Recode' to perform a lossless transfer of the video data into an mp4 container I am getting artifacts in After Effects due to the interframe encoding of this bluray in H264 format. This doesn't seem to be a problem with the Lego Batman movie bluray for some reason, maybe it uses Interframe. Anyway, some frames have block artifacts etc when editing / cutting shots.

**Is there a way to convert this original MP4 stream into the same format without losing data / into an intraframe mp4 for editing purposes?**

I have used various re-encoding methods to H264 and prores that don't result in block artifacts but result in less quality and different colourspace, and, higher file sizes.

In FFMPEG I also tried exporting the mp4 as a png sequence but I assume due to the conversion of YUV to RGB I am getting quite noticeable differences in reds and gamma. I'd also prefer to keep this as a H264 or single video file if possible. Full disclosure, I tried various conversion types rgb24 etc to retain colour info but this didn't work either.

Comment: Export to TIFF. It can store YUV. And interframe --> intraframe is not possible without re-encoding. For editing purposes, best to encode to baseline profile.

Comment: Thanks for your response, what method do you suggest for exporting as TIF? I have done TIF and PNG both with the same colourspace issues when converting to rgb. If I don't convert to rgb I cannot open the files in After Effects. "Unsupported TIFF Space". Would be great to keep the YUV but also be able to open the files to edit. 

Also could you please explain what you mean by encore to 'baseline' profile. Thanks :)

Comment: In the H.264 conversion, add `-profile:v baseline`. This makes ffmpeg skip b-frames during conversion, which AE can have problems with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programming related.

Answer (score 0):

Lossless is probably not going to work - but you can create a high quality motion jpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i your.mp4 -c:v mjpeg -q:v 3 motion_jpeg.mov
```